# Custom AEM Form field not persisted

Tags: adobe, aem

I attempt to create a custom field for `AEM` form `(AEM6.0 SP3)` following how text field does it: `/libs/fd/af/components/guidetextbox`

I created `init.jsp` and widget.jsp with same content.
On widget.jsp, I then add some `jQuery` to `autopopulate text` field on focus out.

```
<script>
var thisField = '${guideid}${'_widget'}';
    $(thisField).focusout(function() {
    $(this).val('date ' + new Date());
  });
</script>
```

On focus in, I type text 'ABC' then when focus-out I get text 'date ' however when submitting the data, text 'ABC' gets submitted.

Is there any `AEM` API I need to invoke (instead of just `jQuery` .val() function) in order for the changes to be recorded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but we managed to get it work by first calling focus(), eg.

```
$(this).focus().val('date ' + new Date());
```

Better solution:

1. create a custom function eg

   function initDatePicker(thisObj) { $(this).focusout(function() {thisObj.value = $(this).val();});}
2. Update .content.xml to call this within initScript eg.

   <cq:template guideNodeClass="guideTextBox" jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" jcr:title="Datepicker input field" initScript="initDatePicker(this)"/>

the function will be immediately included when the widget is added to canvas.

Answer (score 0):

In AEM Forms a Javascript model is maintained that stores the value and that model is used to submit the data. Now to pass on the value from the ui to the model `XFA_EXIT_EVENT`[1] has to be triggered. So after setting the value you must add this line of code to persist the value

```
$(this).trigger(xfalib.ut.XfaUtil.prototype.XFA_EXIT_EVENT)
```

Also a better way would be to create your own widget for this specific scenario. See [2] for more details. The article is for AEM Form 6.1 but it will work for AEM 6.0 as well.

[1] https://helpx.adobe.com/aem-forms/6/html5-forms/introduction-widgets.html

[2] https://helpx.adobe.com/aem-forms/6-1/custom-appearance-widget-adaptive-form.html